# Own Python app + other apps makes system freeze - where to start searching for issues?

Tags: kubuntu, python, 19.04, hp, cpu-load

I wrote a long-running (hours/days) app in Python which takes 100% CPU on one core and around 1GB of RAM - as intended. (load at around 1 according to htop)

Usually, I don't use the `Kubuntu 19.04` HP laptop (`i5 7200, 2.5GHz, 8GB RAM, SSD`) much during these runs.

Occasionally, I need to use it and noticed that the load is shooting up to 20, 30 and higher. The system gets really unresponsive - often the mouse does move slowly but I can't click anything. Sometimes, the load drops and I'm able to close other software. Sometimes I need to power off the laptop after waiting for for 10 - 30 min of high load / unresponsive system / screaming CPU fan.

My impression is, that a combination of my program + Atom and/or my program + Chromium are causing the high load.

The slow mouse seems to be an issue according to Google - mostly related to games / graphic adapter / driver etc.
My case seems to be not covered in the results.

Where should I start digging?

I see this one:

> Jan 18 05:19:37 hpn-HP-Notebook systemd-udevd[468]: 0003:275D:0BA6.0022: Worker [7254] processing SEQNUM=18942 is taking a long time

in `/var/log/syslog` several time.
And I'm running mongodb as well as Apache on the laptop (all just dev environment - no http traffic or so and I keep the mongodb requests very low in my program and use bulk writes only)

The following details when everything is working smooth (Python + Chromium + Atom + LibreOffice Calc)

```
free -h (before starting Python program, with Chromium and Atom running)
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       4.4Gi       213Mi       590Mi       3.1Gi       2.5Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi        12Mi       2.0Gi

free -h (after starting Python program, with Chromium and Atom running)
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       5.6Gi       729Mi       645Mi       1.4Gi       1.2Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi       148Mi       1.9Gi

sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Insyde
       physical id: 0
       version: F.21
       date: 10/27/2016
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 6080KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 128KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 512KiB
       capacity: 512KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 3MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 26
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR Synchronous [empty]
          physical id: 0
          slot: Bottom-slot 1(left)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: M471A1K43CB1-CRC
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 1
          serial: 3491FD06
          slot: Bottom-slot 2(right)
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: Memory controller
       product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 21
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: bus_master
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c142c000-c142ffff
```

Edit:
HP Notebook - 15-ay143tx

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: I've added both outputs - free before and after starting the program.

Comment: Let's try a temporary tweak and see if it helps... in `terminal` type `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=80`. Monitor `free -h`. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: What make/model # is your computer?

Comment: @heynnema I've added the make/model into the post and added the swappiness right after you suggested it. So far, it happened only one more time - when I opened a new tab in Chromium with Bing Maps. Otherwise, the system is running nicely so far - just tried 3 heavy load Python scripts and Chromium and Atom without any issues.

Comment: I'm glad the vm.swappiness tweak improved things a bit. I've written an answer, to include a big BIOS update. If all of this was helpful, please remember to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark and up-arrow icons just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tune Swap...**

We try to temporarily fine-tune your system with:

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=80
```

With only 8G RAM, this will force the system to use more swap.

**Update the BIOS...**

HP Notebook 15-ay143tx

Your BIOS is currently F.21

As per [this web page](https://support.hp.com/hk-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-15-ay100-notebook-pc/12499456/model/13674110), the current BIOS is F.48, from Jan 10, 2020.

- download the update
- backup important files
- install the newer BIOS

**Update #1:**

Since tuning vm.swappiness, we see an improvement in system performance, so we'll make it permanent with these commands...

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.swappiness=80

sudo sysctl -p
```

Ultimately more RAM and more SWAP would make further improvement.